# Why doesn't my rspec test pass when my model validation fails as it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

My model has validation like:

```
 # Account Model
    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :password, presence: true
```

So I created a factory_girl for this model that has blank values like:

```
 factory :account do
  end

 trait :empty do
    email ""
    password ""
  end
```

So my test looks like:

```
it "doesn't allow empty fields" do
  account = create(:account, :empty)
  account.should_not be_valid
end
```

So I am saying that this model, with empty fields, should fail the validation with "should_not".

Yet when I run rspec I get this error:

```
Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/account_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What is the problem with my test?

Comment: try `account = build(:account, :empty)` this not save to db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rspec error comes from this line  `account = create(:account, :empty)`, not this one `account.should_not be_valid`

`create` will attempt to create the record in the database, and go through the validation. use `build` instead